# Executing stored procedure with Parameters on Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to execute a stored procedure on Linked Server (`MyLS`).
The stored procedure on `MyLS` takes a Table-Value parameter (`MyTblType`) and looks like  `MyLSProc @tbl as MyTblType READONLY...` 
On my local server, in some stored procedure  I have defined

```
DECLARE @MyTbl as MyTblType
```

and trying to call

```
EXEC (MyLSProc @MyTbl) AT [MyLS]
```

but get an error

> Must declare the scalar variable @MyTbl.

Is there way to resolve this problem?

Comment: can you show the execute statement ?

Comment: table types can't be shared by different databases (even if they are on the same server, let alone on different servers). What you can do is execute a script of dynamic sql to create and populate the equivalent table type on the linked server with the values you have on your current server, and then execute the stored procedure. See [this so post for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16536693) (Not marking as duplicate because it lacks explanations).

Comment: You will always get that error as you need to declare that variable. SQL is looking for your declaration for that variable. A typical example of it would be like `DECLARE @MyTbl as MyTblType 
EXEC (MyLSProc @MyTbl) AT [MyLS] `
Then SQL knows what it is. For us to assist you better, share your stored procedure on both server/s...